# (kotlin) editText.toString().toInt() isn't work in anroid studio

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, kotlin-generics

```
val editText1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText1);

if(comNum != editText1.toString().toInt() ){

 View4.text = "오답"
            } else View4.text = "정답"
```

The installed  `apk` is not working. I think `edittext.toString.toInt` is wrong.

Comment: Can you post stack trace from logcat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the `String` out of `EditText`: `editText1.getText().toString().toInt()`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! i handled almost 3 hours ㅠㅠ. very very thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong**

```
 editText1.toString().toInt()
```

It should be

```
editText1.text.toString().toInt()
```

**FYI**

[**`toInt()`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) Parses the string as an Int number and returns the result. if the string is not a valid representation of a number you will receive [**NumberFormatException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 val editText1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText1);

  if(comNum != Integer.parseInt(editText1.text.toString()) ){

     View4.text = "오답"
        } else View4.text = "정답"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, you can not using  `editText1.toString().toInt()`

```
  var value: Int

  try {
         value =  editText1.text.toString().toInt();
  } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
         // value of editText1 is a invalid Integer
  }
  if(comNum != value ){
  View4.text = "오답"
  } else View4.text = "정답"
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
editText1.text.toString().toInt()
```